# Sending data from excel (selenium basic) to the calendar on the web page

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, dom, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker on my web page and it says 06.11.2021 08:55 by selecting the day, hour and minute first. With the code in the picture, I can get the text information of the days from the class of the datepicker, but I don't know how to select them. What I want is; If 6 is written in cell a1 in excel, I want to make it select the 6th day in the sheet.

**My code:**

```
    Dim y As Selenium.SelectElement
Dim g As Selenium.SelectElement
Dim c As Selenium.WebElement
x.Start "Chrome"
x.Get "https://xxxxxxxx.com.tr/Account/Login"

x.FindElementByName("txtUsername").SendKeys "1xxxxx"
x.FindElementByName("txtPassword").SendKeys ("xxxxxxxxxx")
x.Wait 1000
x.FindElementByName("btnLogin").Click
'MsgBox ("no element found")
x.Wait 3000
x.Get "https://ccc.xxxxxx.com.tr/Cihaz/IsletmeFaaliyet/5cf3a28c-a3e4-4c52-b481-98e85fec3fea"
Set y = x.FindElementById("ddlIsletmeFaaliyetTur").AsSelect
y.SelectByText Range("u2")
x.FindElementById("txtFaaliyetTarihBaslangic").Click
x.Wait 2000

Set c = x.FindElementsByClass(" datetimepicker-days")(1)
Debug.Print c.Text
```

**calendar related codes:**

```
<input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control" id="txtFaaliyetTarihBaslangic" name="txtFaaliyetTarihBaslangic"><div class="datetimepicker-minutes" style="display: none;"><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></th><th colspan="5" class="switch">1 Kasım 2021</th><th class="next" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="minute">8:00</span><span class="minute active">8:05</span><span class="minute">8:10</span><span class="minute">8:15</span><span class="minute">8:20</span><span class="minute">8:25</span><span class="minute">8:30</span><span class="minute">8:35</span><span class="minute">8:40</span><span class="minute">8:45</span><span class="minute">8:50</span><span class="minute">8:55</span></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Bugün</th></tr></tfoot></table></div>
<div class="datetimepicker-hours" style="display: none;"><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></th><th colspan="5" class="switch">1 Kasım 2021</th><th class="next" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="hour">0:00</span><span class="hour">1:00</span><span class="hour">2:00</span><span class="hour">3:00</span><span class="hour">4:00</span><span class="hour">5:00</span><span class="hour">6:00</span><span class="hour">7:00</span><span class="hour active">8:00</span><span class="hour">9:00</span><span class="hour">10:00</span><span class="hour">11:00</span><span class="hour">12:00</span><span class="hour">13:00</span><span class="hour">14:00</span><span class="hour">15:00</span><span class="hour">16:00</span><span class="hour">17:00</span><span class="hour">18:00</span><span class="hour">19:00</span><span class="hour">20:00</span><span class="hour">21:00</span><span class="hour">22:00</span><span class="hour">23:00</span></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Bugün</th></tr></tfoot></table></div>
<div class="datetimepicker-days" style="display: block;"><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></th><th colspan="5" class="switch">Kasım 2021</th><th class="next" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Pz</th><th class="dow">Pzt</th><th class="dow">Sa</th><th class="dow">Çr</th><th class="dow">Pr</th><th class="dow">Cu</th><th class="dow">Ct</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day old">31</td><td class="day active">1</td><td class="day">2</td><td class="day">3</td><td class="day">4</td><td class="day">5</td><td class="day">6</td></tr><tr><td class="day">7</td><td class="day">8</td><td class="day">9</td><td class="day">10</td><td class="day">11</td><td class="day">12</td><td class="day">13</td></tr><tr><td class="day">14</td><td class="day">15</td><td class="day">16</td><td class="day">17</td><td class="day">18</td><td class="day">19</td><td class="day">20</td></tr><tr><td class="day">21</td><td class="day">22</td><td class="day">23</td><td class="day">24</td><td class="day">25</td><td class="day">26</td><td class="day">27</td></tr><tr><td class="day">28</td><td class="day">29</td><td class="day">30</td><td class="day new">1</td><td class="day new">2</td><td class="day new">3</td><td class="day new">4</td></tr><tr><td class="day new">5</td><td class="day new">6</td><td class="day new">7</td><td class="day new">8</td><td class="day new">9</td><td class="day new">10</td><td class="day new">11</td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Bugün</th></tr></tfoot></table></div>
<div class="datetimepicker-months" style="display: none;"><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2021</th><th class="next" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Oca</span><span class="month">Şub</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Nis</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">Haz</span><span class="month">Tem</span><span class="month">Ağu</span><span class="month">Eyl</span><span class="month">Eki</span><span class="month active">Kas</span><span class="month">Ara</span></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Bugün</th></tr></tfoot></table></div>
<div class="datetimepicker-years" style="display: none;"><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2020-2029</th><th class="next" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2019</span><span class="year">2020</span><span class="year active">2021</span><span class="year">2022</span><span class="year">2023</span><span class="year">2024</span><span class="year">2025</span><span class="year">2026</span><span class="year">2027</span><span class="year">2028</span><span class="year">2029</span><span class="year old">2030</span></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Bugün</th></tr></tfoot></table></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='datetimepicker-days']").FindElementByXPath("//td[text()='" & dd & "']").Click
```

this is the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).